# Machine Learning using NLP results

Tags: r, natural-language

I have a large data set with over a million  products. The NLP results look like this: [image: this]

A random row (reshaped) looks like this: [image: this]

The dataframe (image) contains information derived from the tokenization of a single product (" Dipperwell Faucet with Drain Stainless Steel Bowl Inner Overflow Cup").

Is it possible to predict the word "faucet" given the NLP output. The ML algorithms I am familiar with usually are in a format

Prediction~ Predictor 1+ Predictor 2.. etc..

In this case , the predictors are columns and the predicted value is a cell

Comment: "Is it possible"? I suppose so. Can you make your question more specific?

Comment: How do you recommend I do it? I will have to manually create a training set where the predicted variable is a token/ a combination of tokens.

Comment: What is the NLP output?

Comment: The output is tokens, POS and relationship between tokens . Thus, all categorical variables

Comment: don't post images of data. hard to copy and paste and read

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to tag/classify your products into product "buckets" like faucets?

If so, the features you've proposed are ill-suited to a statistical approach. You should investigate word vectors as features. https://cs.stanford.edu/~quocle/paragraph_vector.pdf

You will still need to annotate a dataset, or provide "faucet" for each of some set observations for training. You could use the NLP techniques you're already employing to automate a portion of that work, effectively giving you a "suggestion" for you to review and edit if necessary.